# Query para obtener lista de objetos ordenados por el último agregado en Firebase

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase

Estoy tratando de obtener una lista ordenada por el último objeto agregado en el primer puesto pero no lo he podido lograr con las funciones de firebase.

```
ref.orderByKey().once('value', function(res){...})
```